# How can I make a scroll that goes straight to another parallax?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, parallax

As a test to see if I am really understanding my web courses and how to make the most of it, I started building "my website", and I had the idea of a scroll that goes straight to another image the moment the user tries to scroll.

The idea is a scroll like the one here: https://mariamsg.com/

I've seen other answers here in stack overflow but even though I try to, I can't replicate them, and to be honest, even if I would be able to, I wouldn't be able to actually learn anything because I'd still not understand it.

If someone could explain to me how to pull this off and how the code works, it'd be awesome.

Before dropping my code below, I'd like to in advance thank you for taking your time with me!!

```css
.parallax {
  background-image: url("../ASSETS/back_2.JPG");
  height: 102%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: -2rem;
}

.parallax2 {
  background-image: url("../ASSETS/back.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../ASSETS/itu_white.png"></a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item current">
          <a class="nav-link dsa ndrln" href="#">Yo</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dsa ndrln" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Portfolio
                </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu animate slideIn" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fotos</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Videos</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sitios</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link dsa ndrln" href="#">Contacto</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="itu-content">
    <h1 class="heading">&#xa1;Hola!</h1>
    <h2 class="subheading">&#xa1;Bienvenido/a a Itu!</h2>
    <p>Ac&aacute; pod&eacute;s conocer mis proyectos y hobbies actuales</p>
  </div>
  <div class="gotointro">
    <a href="#intro" class="btn-intro"><img src="../ASSETS/iralaintro_empty.png" class="vacio" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax2" id="intro">
```

Comment: you need fullpage.js, or you can use pagepiling js as well, check this https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js

Comment: @AtulRajput thank you so so much! With pagepiling.js I just followed the instructions and it already works! Will keep studying it so I can learn how to improve the looks. Again, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

> "Stop using unnecessary libraries. Start doing things on your own."
> *-mmaismma (August 10, 2020)*

## Use CSS Scroll Snap

No need to use Javascript to produce that effect. We have CSS properties specifically made for the purpose. These properties have got [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-snappoints) from all popular browsers except Internet Explorer (it has got partial support using `-ms-` prefix). Check the **Further Reading** section at the end to know more.

This snippet should answer your question. (Run in *Full Page* for the best experience)

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.container div {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
}

.sec1 {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/%21_Russisch-Orthodoxe_Kirche_%28Dresden%29_Glockenturm.jpg);
}

.sec2 {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1f/%21_Russisch-Orthodoxe_Kirche_%28Dresden%29_Zwiebelt%C3%BCrme.JPG/320px-%21_Russisch-Orthodoxe_Kirche_%28Dresden%29_Zwiebelt%C3%BCrme.JPG);
}

.sec3 {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/%21941_Lincoln_Continental_Coupe%2C_Series_57_-_Automobile_Driving_Museum_-_El_Segundo%2C_CA_-_DSC01970.jpg/320px-%21941_Lincoln_Continental_Coupe%2C_Series_57_-_Automobile_Driving_Museum_-_El_Segundo%2C_CA_-_DSC01970.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sec1">
    Section one
  </div>
  <div class="sec2">
    Section two
  </div>
  <div class="sec3">
    Section three
  </div>
</div>
```

## Further Reading

- [Basic concepts of CSS Scroll Snap on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts)
- [How to use CSS Scroll Snap on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-use-css-scroll-snap/)
- [CSS Scroll Snap on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap)